# cassert file not found but i use Box2d template

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, box2d-iphone

i am using cocos2d template with Box2d but when i import Box2d.h in my project it gives me error 
cassert fiel not found 
i have cocos2d version 2.0
please help me

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure all your project's source code files have the file extension .mm and not .m. Or set each .m file's type to Objective-C++.

Comment: i change file extension .m to .mm but just those files which i was created. here is lots od cocos2d files founds with.m

Answer (score 1):

change your file extension .mm thats it

Answer (score 0):

Changing extension in xcode 4 will not work. Instead go to build settings (tab) and change C++ standard library setting to libc++ (LLVM...) from compiler default.

If you build it now you will get an error saying app is not compatible with iOS 5 or later. So go to summary (tab) and change deployment target to 5.0. It should now build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the issue. Cleaning up and recreating the project didn't seem to be a good idea for me.

There are a couple of answers on the web for this issue but they in each didn't help me solve the problem. One is on SO at

[cassert file not found but i use Box2d template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108692/cassert-file-not-found-but-i-use-box2d-template) and the other is on cocos2d-iphone forum,

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cannot-include-box2d-cassert-file-not-found-despite-every-file-being-mm/

Combining the two suggestions kind of worked for me -

> 1. Rename all YOUR (not cocos2d or box2d files, just your project files) from .m to .mm
> 2. Make sure that on each of the files, on the right pane, “Type” option is set to “Default – Objective C++ Source”

There was another issue for me specifically, may not be an issue for you, I was using the following signature for CCLabelTTF

```
CCLabelTTF *title = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello" dimensions:CGSizeMake(720.0f, 880.0f) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:34];
```

This is deprecated and caused errors all over the place. I am now using the following slightly modified version and the errors fixed -

```
CCLabelTTF *title = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello" dimensions:CGSizeMake(720.0f, 880.0f) hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:34];
```

My most recent writeup of this fix can be found at - http://indiangamer.com/how-i-fixed-the-cocos2d-box2d-include-file-not-found-error/

Answer (score 0):

For those like me : I just tried to reopen a very old xcode project and got this error with cassert files.

Just setting the target to a new one (iOS 13 in my case) made it automatically select the correct version of the c++ stdlib and everything worked just fine.