# Lexical or preprocessor error: file not found using box2d & cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm having this weird issue when building my project. The problem is as follows:

My friend and I are working on a project and we're exactly using the same xcode, cocos2d and box2d versions.
His project compiles (builds) fine while mine gives this error when I do:
cassert file not found.

I took a copy of his xcode.project but no problems whatsoever.

I hope this code summarizes better what I'm trying to say:

```
GameLayer.h
#import bla bla //the usual required files
@class myOwnClass1;
@class myOwnClass2;

myOwnClass1 *test1;
myOwnClass2 *test2;
```

Now I wanna include the `GameLayer.h` in either `myOwnClass1.h` or `myOwnClass2.h` using `#import` but it would give me the error!
If I did `@class GameLayer;` no problems at all.

The thing is in my friend's project he's doing the `#import` without the error, which is super weird (at least for me)

Advice?

P.S. I know that changing the `.m` to `.mm` would solve it but, again, in my friend's project he's using the `.m`

Comment: could you paste the exact error message text that you get? and specify which line is flagged?

Comment: the exact error message is: `lexical or preprocessor error: file not found` and shows the `#include <cassert>` line of code included in the `b2dsettings.h`. If this is not enough for you, i'll post some code when I get home (macbook @home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it turned out that creating a new project from scratch solved the problem, I'll mark this as the correct answer for now unless someone else has another opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a mismatch of compiler settings between your project and your friend's.

In short: `cassert` is a C++ header file; you definitely need a C++ compiler to compile it.

Now, my guess is that in your friend's project, the GameLayer.m file is marked as a C++ file, though it has got a `.m` extension.

To verify that, open your project's (and your friend's) `project.pbxproj` file in a text editor and look for the GameLayer.m file. You will get this kind of entry:

```
    347F5D94158BA4840058BC21 /* main.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = main.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

as you see, the `lastKnownFileType` key says `sourcecode.c.objc`: this identifies an Objective-C file. If you see `sourcecode.cpp.objcpp`, that means objective c++.

Hope this helps clarifying it.

Comment: I'll definitely check it out when I finish work. When I checked with him he told me that he didn't modify anything nor manipulated any settings, anyhow I cant be sure unless I check it myself. Thanks @sergio

Comment: negative, we both have it the same `D87300F41679D0E900CF1744 /* main.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = main.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };` and mine `635CEB9D167FAC22005BB58B /* main.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = main.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };`

Comment: Can I close the question? We did another project from the ground up and it's working, no idea why the old one wouldn't. So I thought we could close this question.

Comment: or you might add your finding (that the fix was creating a new project) as the accepted answer for someone else getting into the same...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the issue. Cleaning up and recreating the project didn't seem to be a good idea for me.

There are a couple of answers on the web for this issue but they in each didn't help me solve the problem. One is on SO at

[cassert file not found but i use Box2d template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108692/cassert-file-not-found-but-i-use-box2d-template) and the other is on cocos2d-iphone forum,

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cannot-include-box2d-cassert-file-not-found-despite-every-file-being-mm/

Combining the two suggestions kind of worked for me -

> 1. Rename all YOUR (not cocos2d or box2d files, just your project files) from .m to .mm
> 2. Make sure that on each of the files, on the right pane, “Type” option is set to “Default – Objective C++ Source”

There was another issue for me specifically, may not be an issue for you, I was using the following signature for CCLabelTTF

```
CCLabelTTF *title = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello" dimensions:CGSizeMake(720.0f, 880.0f) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:34];
```

This is deprecated and caused errors all over the place. I am now using the following slightly modified version and the errors fixed -

```
CCLabelTTF *title = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello" dimensions:CGSizeMake(720.0f, 880.0f) hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:34];
```

My most recent writeup of this fix can be found at - http://indiangamer.com/how-i-fixed-the-cocos2d-box2d-include-file-not-found-error/